# Inverting matrix with Sherman-Morrison formula

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

I am reading [this book](https://e-maxx.ru/bookz/files/numerical_recipes.pdf) but I am struggling with a formula. Let $A$ a square matrix $N \times N$ partitioned as $\mathbf{A}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\mathbf{P} & \mathbf{Q} \\
\mathbf{R} & \mathbf{S}
\end{array}\right]$. If its inverse is partitioned in the same manner, $\mathbf{A}^{-1}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\tilde{\mathbf{P}} & \tilde{\mathbf{Q}} \\
\widetilde{\mathbf{R}} & \widetilde{\mathbf{S}}
\end{array}\right]$, then,
\begin{aligned}
&\widetilde{\mathbf{P}}=\left(\mathbf{P}-\mathbf{Q} \cdot \mathbf{S}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{R}\right)^{-1} \\
&\tilde{\mathbf{Q}}=-\left(\mathbf{P}-\mathbf{Q} \cdot \mathbf{S}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{R}\right)^{-1} \cdot\left(\mathbf{Q} \cdot \mathbf{S}^{-1}\right) \\
&\widetilde{\mathbf{R}}=-\left(\mathbf{S}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{R}\right) \cdot\left(\mathbf{P}-\mathbf{Q} \cdot \mathbf{S}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{R}\right)^{-1} \\
&\widetilde{\mathbf{S}}=\mathbf{S}^{-1}+\left(\mathbf{S}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{R}\right) \cdot\left(\mathbf{P}-\mathbf{Q} \cdot \mathbf{S}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{R}\right)^{-1} \cdot\left(\mathbf{Q} \cdot \mathbf{S}^{-1}\right)
\end{aligned}

I believe it is using the Sherman-Morrison formula, presented in the previous section. It states that if we change the matrix A in the form $\mathbf{A} \rightarrow(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{u} \otimes \mathbf{v})$ for some vector $u,v$ and $u \otimes v$ is a matrix whose $i,j$-th element is the product of the $i$th component of $u$ and the $j$-th component of $v$. Then,
$(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{u} \otimes \mathbf{v})^{-1} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}-\frac{\left(\mathbf{A}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{u}\right) \otimes\left(\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{A}^{-1}\right)}{1+\lambda}$ with $\lambda \equiv \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{A}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{u}$

Any help? I only want to figure out the formula for $\widetilde{\mathbf{P}}$. Given that one, I will try to figure out the others

Comment: No, it's blockwise Gaussian elimination. See the "Background" section in Wikipedia's entry on [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Background).

Comment: Thank you so much!